# Show that the eigenvalues of $A+B$ is the sum of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $AB=BA$. Show that the eigenvalues of $A+B$ is the sum of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

First I tried to find a counterexample and I found out this property without proof.

Comment: I am sure this has been discussed here before. (Anyway, Please, do not ask questions in the imperative, this is considered as impolite here).

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3160755/8157), for example.